# Catching all bad signals for called commands in Bash script

Tags: bash, error-handling, signals

We are creating a bash script for a build server. We want to ensure that when we execute a bash command inside the script, it returns with a signal of 0. If it does not, we want execution to stop. Our solution so far is to do:

```
#some command
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    #handle error
fi
```

after *every* command that could cause this problem. This makes the code quite long and doesn't seem very elegant. We could use a bash function, perhaps. Although working with $? can be a bit tricky, and we would still have to call the function after every command. Is there a better way? I've looked at the **trap** command but it seems to only do signal handling with the bash script I am writing, not any commands I call.

Comment: `$?` is the exit code. Exit codes and signals are not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The robust, canonical way of doing this is:

```
#!/bin/bash
die() {
  local ret=$?
  echo >&2 "$*"
  exit "$ret"
}

./configure  || die "Project can't be configured"
make         || die "Project doesn't build"
make install || die "Installation failed"
```

The fragile, convenient way of doing this is `set -e`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e     # Script will exit in many (but not all) cases if a command fails

./configure
make
make install
```

or equivalently (with a custom error message):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Will be called for many (but not all) commands that fail
trap 'ret=$?; echo >&2 "Failure on line $LINENO, exiting."; exit $ret' ERR

./configure
make
make install
```

---

For the latter two, the script will not exit for any command that is part of a conditional statement or `&&`/`||`, so while:

```
backup() {
  set -e
  scp backup.tar.gz user@host:/backup
  rm backup.tar.gz
}
backup
```

will correctly avoid executing `rm` if the transfer fails, later inserting a feature like this:

```
if backup
then
  mail -s "Backup completed successfully" user@example.com
fi
```

will make the `backup` stop exiting on failure and accidentally delete backups.

Comment: This works! Thanks for the help. I'm probably going to use the third one. Does ERR just catch any non-zero signal? If so, can I also put in traps for other signals, such as displaying a specific message on a SIGSEGV, and have it take priority over the default ERR trap?

Comment: ERR does not catch any signal at all. It triggers when a command returns a non-zero exit code. Exit codes and signals are different things. A process being killed by signal SIGSEGV (11) and a process exiting with code 11 is not in any way related.

Comment: Okay. We will keep this and the recent edits in mind when we do our scripting.